# Excluding specific keyword from a file

Tags: shell-script, grep

I am trying to write a shell script which will grep for keywords which should be excluded from a file, if it finds anything else from excluded one, It should execute specific command..

```
logcheck=`grep -vq 'accepting\|idle.' /tmp/lpstat-Final.log`

    if [[ $logcheck == 'accepting\|idle.' ]] ; then
        status=0
        statustxt=OK
    else
    echo "Something found"
    fi
```

The outcome should be If anything apart from 'accepting\|idle.' found it should go to else statement or else the exist status will be 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ! grep -Evq 'accepting|idle' /tmp/lpstat-Final.log; then
    status=0
    statustxt=OK
else
    echo 'Something found'
fi
```

The main thing here is that `grep` will not produce any output if you use `-q`. This means that using a command substitution will not capture anything (`$logcheck` in your code will be empty).  Instead, we use the exit status of the utility to determine whether something was found or not.

I'm using `-E` here to make the regular expression prettier; it is also needed for alternation (alteration with `\|` in a basic regular expression is an extension, supported by e.g. GNU `grep`).